# Why won't UIScrollView scroll fully after adding objects? Using storyboard, ARC, and Xcode 4.5.2

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, storyboard, autolayout

So, I know there are similar questions to mine, but maybe not exact (so please don't mark me down -- just warn me or something). I have searched for days for the solution to this SIMPLE issue.  Using storyboards, ARC, and Xcode 4.5.2, I simply need to put a bunch of labels inside a UIScrollView and have it scroll vertically. I've tried so many combinations of setting frame sizes and content sizes within viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, and viewWillAppear, but to no avail. **The scroll view scrolls perfectly when there's nothing inside of it, but when I add labels to it, the scrolling only scrolls a very short section.**

Note: I need to use auto layout, otherwise my whole project will get messed up.

Here's my current code...

**.h file:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MortgageRatesViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIScrollViewAccessibilityDelegate>

- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mortgageView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

**.m file:**

```
#import "MortgageRatesViewController.h"


@interface MortgageRatesViewController ()

@end

@implementation MortgageRatesViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"appBackgroundColor.png"]];


    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, 809)];



}

//---------------------------------------------------------------

//---------------------------------------------------------------

//-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
//    
//    
//    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
//    
//    
//    [self.scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 808)];   
//
//    
//}

//---------------------------------------------------------------

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, 809)];

}

//-------------------------------------------------------------

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NO];

}
@end
```

**Note: having viewWillAppear commented out has made no difference.**

**EDIT: I POSTED THE SOLUTION BELOW. HOPE IT HELPS OTHERS!**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After days of research, it's funny I actually found the solution just minutes after posting this question!  So, for my situation I simply had to add this bit of code, and it worked:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 808)];
}
```

It seems to be working perfectly now.  Please, anyone, let me know if this is a poor way of doing it, because I'm new to this and I would love any help. Otherwise, I'll leave it and hope this can help other people! Thanks!

Comment: yeah, i met the same problem. frustrating :S

Comment: you dont need the setContentSize in the other methods and dont need setScrollEnabled message.  Only viewDidLayoutSubviews.  If you turn on automatic layout then multiply the desired size by 1.52... so if you wanted scrollable size of 1000 make the CGSizeRect 1000*1.52 for the height

Comment: correction for my comment above:  you dont need the setContentSize in the other methods and dont need setScrollEnabled message.  Only viewDidLayoutSubviews.  If you turn on automatic layout then make sure your UIScrollView constraints are set top/left/right/bottom width/height else it wont scroll correctly.

Comment: Great solution, thank you. But Apple, why do we need to do this? Scroll views are used in many, many apps yet they are a total PIA to work with. There's go to be a better way to do this!!!

Comment: Setting hard coded values is not a good idea... what happens if you code is running on different screen sizes? (3.5, 4, 4.7, 5.5...)

Comment: @Islam Q. yes I agree, nowadays I don't ever set hard-coded values. I was very new to development in 2012 when I posted this. Now I always set frames relative to screen size and also the other UI elements on the screen, and I do everything programmatically.

Comment: @LargeGlasses I think it would be better to use autolayout and size-classes (especially with the new multitasking feature)

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION with Storyboard + Autolayout (no code):**

Vertical scrolling example that starts from top-left corner:

- Set the **top+leading** constraints of the first object (subview)
- **Chain up** every object till the last one
- The **most important** - set the **bottom constraint** to the scroll view so it's hooked up top to bottom.
- Set the `width` of the scroll view - either a specific "magic number" or a better way - connect the trailing constraint of a subview that has a set width - if there's non I usually set a label's width = screen width -  side paddings => **standard**(20)+**UILabel**(280)+**standard**(20) - this way the scroll view knows exactly its content's width, otherwise you'll get an "ambiguous width" warning.

*Needs constraints' adjustments if horizontal scrolling is desired.

Answer (score 2):

your scrollview's frame is not the scrollable size.

Check out contentSize

Set frame to its superview.bounds then set content size to the scroolview's scrollable area.

Also I dont know that the background will scroll.

You will want to add subview's to the scrollview itself.

It should scroll its own subviews. but it will not scroll itself :)