# iOS: how to set constraints to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I would like to implement a simple `UIViewController` with vertically scrollable content.

I have been trying to use `UIScrollView`, but I am struggling with setting the constraints in Interface Builder. Can anyone illustrate the proper way to do it?

Let's consider a page which has a `UILabel` with a long text and a couple of `UIImageView`s placed at the bottom of the text.

Comment: I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25215562/2177402) a similar question, can you double check please?

Comment: Have a look on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133144/uiscrollview-and-constraints/26135270#26135270).

Answer (score 1):

`UIScrollView` has 2 important properties when dealing with `autolayout` constraint and scrolling function. Those are size and content size.

`UIScrollView` size is the size of `UIScrollView` related to its superview.
You can set its constraint by pin each of top, trailing, leading, bottom to its superview.

`UIScrollView` content size on the other hand is the size of `UIScrollView` subview related to it. It is basically the scrollable size. Setting the constraint of its subview is a little bit tricky, you can't just pin each side of each subview to `UIScrollView`. You also need to add some height and width constraint to it so it won't give ambiously constraint warning.

Let's say for example that you have one `UILabel` and one `UIImageView` below the label.

A simple way to create vertically scrollable content would be:

1. set top, leading, trailing space constraint of `UILabel` to `UIScrollView`
2. set `UILabel` height and width constraint
3. connect height constraint to code so you can modify its value.
4. set `UIImageView` top constraint to `UILabel`
5. set `UIIMageView` trailing, leading and bottom space constraint to `UIScrollView`
6. set `UIImageView` height and width constraint
7. change `UILabel` height constraint based on the text and call `layoutIfNeeded`